# What is the best way to split a line of numbers separated by a marker and spaces and store it into a tuple?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a text file with numbers separated by colons and spaces as the following.

```
0:-83 1: -51 2: -69 3: -82 4: -85 8: -90 9: -69 QUAD
0:-88 1: -88 2: -98 3: -75 4: -42 5: -71 6: -89 7: -28 8: -83 9: -78 STADIUM
```

A pair is defined as two numbers separated by a colon. Spaces interrupt pairs of numbers arbitrarily.

Currently, I have the following.

```
with open('data.txt') as file:
  lines = file.read().splitlines()
for line in lines: 
  line = line[:-1]  
  # What is the regex I should be using? 
  # data = re.split(r'[:\s]',line) includes the space after the colon if it exists
```

What is the best way to parse the text file so that each line is stored as a list of tuples where each tuple is a pair?

Comment: whats your expected output here?

Comment: There is no output; I am parsing and storing data from the text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regex will give you your pairs of numbers (including minus signs) in groups:

```
r'\b(-?\d+)\s*:\s*(-?\d+)\b'
```

This matches a word-boundary (`\b`), then a set of digits (with an optional `-` minus sign before it), followed by a colon surrounded by optional whitespace, followed by another set of digits with optional minus sign, followed by a word boundary.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> numpairs = re.compile(r'\b(-?\d+)\s*:\s*(-?\d+)\b')
>>> example = '0:-83 1: -51 2: -69 3: -82 4: -85 8: -90 9: -69 QUAD'
>>> numpairs.findall(example)
[('0', '-83'), ('1', '-51'), ('2', '-69'), ('3', '-82'), ('4', '-85'), ('8', '-90'), ('9', '-69')]
```

You probably *don't* want to reach all lines into memory at once; just loop over your file line by line:

```
import re
numpairs = re.compile(r'\b(-?\d+)\s*:\s*(-?\d+)\b')
with open('data.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        for pair in numpairs.findall(line):
            print pair
```

You don't need to remove the newline for the above code to work, but if you do, use `line.strip()` instead of `line[:-1]`.

Comment: Is there a way I can cast the items in the pair as an int as I identify them?

Comment: @idealistikz: sure, call `int()` on the string representation of the int. To do this for all matches: `[int(t[0], t[1]) for t in numpairs.findall(example)]`

Answer (score 1):

Um... regex? Why?

How about something like this:

```
result = [] # list of tuples
for line in your_file:
    fields = line.split(':')
    first = int(fields[0].strip())
    fields = fields[1:] # remove first field
    for field in fields:
        last, new_first = [int(x.strip()) for x in field.split(':')]
        result.append((first, last))
        first = new_first
```

...but what about the last field (QUAD, STADION)? you should be able to handle that now, though...

Answer (score 0):

First off, it is much simpler to code `for line in file:`
You can use the regex from Martijn to get at the numbers.

```
for line in file:
    marker = line.split()[-1]
    numbers = re.findall(r'\b(\d+)\s*:\s*(\d+)\b', line)
```